# Best order to place the Fetch or FetchMany in nHibernate Linq statements

Tags: c#, linq, fluent-nhibernate

If you do an nHiberante Linq query and you want to eager load the related objects.
Where do you put the `Fetch` or the `FetchMany` ?

Like this:

```
_session.Query<Entity>()
    .Where(x => x.IsSomething)
    .FetchMany(x => x.Children);
```

Or like this:

```
_session.Query<Entity>()
    .FetchMany(x => x.Children)
    .Where(x => x.IsSomething);
```

I want to know the best order to place the `Fetch` or `FetchMany` (For performance). Or does the order even matter? When I use entity framework i always write the includes first, is this the same case in nHibernate?

We use the specification pattern with nHibernate. So is it smart to put the `Fetch` or `FetchMany` in the specifications?

Comment: Just monitor the SQL that is generated. As for the specification: no. Specification is meant as an abstraction of DAL implementation. You just specify criteria and let the DAL decide how to figure them out. Inside the DAL you would probably `Fetch` depending on the specified criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't matter. IQueryable is just a query statement and Fetch(), FetchMany() is just a setting on the Nhibernate query which enlarge the query to return more data so that you don't perform lazy loading later on. The query is not sent to the database until you call ToList(), Single() etc. The linq query is then transformed into a sql query which will contain more joins and columns and THEN it is sent to the database server.

The following query will do a "similar" join when fetching the entity + children but here I map it into a anonymous object:

```
_session
    .Query<Entity>()
    .Where(x => x.IsSomething)
    .Select(x => new { MyEntity = x, MyEntitiesChildren = x.Children });
```